# Showing $c_0$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis

Let $c_0$ be the vector space of all convergent sequences $x = \{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ $ \ $ with: $ \ $ $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$. Let $\lVert x \rVert_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_n \rvert$. Consider a Cauchy Sequence $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $c_0$ whose elements are denoted by $x_k = \{ x_{k,n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$
$ \\ $

1. show that for each fixed $ n \in \mathbb{N}, \{ x_{k,n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$
2. Deduce that the limit $y_n = lim_{k \to \infty} x_{k,n}$ defines $y = \{ y_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ with $ \lVert y \rVert_{\infty} \lt \infty$
3. Show that $lim_{k \to \infty} \lVert x_k - y \rVert_{\infty} = 0$
4. Conclude that $y \in c_o$ and thus $c_0$ is complete.

$ \\ $

My attempt:

Visualization-
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
    x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
    \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
    \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
    \cdot  & \cdot  & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$ \\ $

So, $\{ x_{k,n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of sequences like the above and each row $\to 0$.

Now, fixing $n \in \mathbb{N}$ lets me deal with an individual column of the above. Since $\{ x_{k} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $c_0$, for $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \ \exists M \in \mathbb{N} \ $ s.t. $ \ m,m' \ge M \implies \lVert x_m - x_{m'} \rVert \lt \epsilon.$

So,
$$
      m,m' \ge M \implies \lvert x_{m,n} - x_{m',n} \rvert \lt \epsilon; \ \ \forall n \ge 1
$$
Therefore, when n is fixed, $\{ x_{k,n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$

Because $\{ x_{k,n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, the limit exists and $\lim_{k \to \infty} \{ x_{k,n} \}_{n=1}^\infty = y_n$

Now, there is a new sequence using the limit of each column involved, let's call it: $y = \{ y_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ (Note: I'm drawing a blank on formal reason why $\lVert y \rVert_{\infty} \lt \infty$)

Letting $m' \to \infty$ in the above result, we get:
$$
     m \ge M \implies \lvert x_{m,n} - y_n \rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}; \ \ \forall n \ge 1
$$
Setting m = M, $\forall n \ge 1$, we have:
$$
      \lvert y_n \rvert = \lvert y_n - x_{M,n} + x_{M,n} \le \lvert y_n - x_{M,n} \rvert + \lvert x_{M,n} \rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \lvert x_{M,n} \rvert
$$
Since $x_M \in c_0$ we have $x_{M,n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$; $\ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ $ \ $ s.t. $ \ $ $n \ge N \implies \lvert x_{M,n} \rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Hence:
$$
      n \ge N \implies \lvert y_n \rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \lvert x_{M,n} \rvert \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon
$$
Therefore, $y \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, thus $ y \in c_0$ and $c_0$ is complete.

Also, $y$ is the limit of the $x_k$'s

And so:
$$
      \lVert x_k - y \rVert_{\infty} = sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_k - y \rvert \lt \epsilon
$$
Which means:
$$
      \lim_{k \to \infty} \lVert x_k - y \rVert_{\infty} = 0
$$
$ \ \ $

I probably messed up and the notation is making my head spin. Am I going about this right?